# Multiply Accumulate Unit

Tags: vhdl

I have a *MAC* unit for a transport triggered architecture processor, but for some reason. the multiply-accumulate part isn't working. I tested it separately and it worked, but when simulated `out_reg_int` is always `0` even though `op_a` and `op_b` are the correct values and I have included `Numeric_STD`.

```
-- These are just for the question
num_in_reg := 2;
num_reg := 4;
data_size := 71;
data_width := 64;

SIGNAL op_a, op_b : SIGNED(data_width-1 DOWNTO 0);
Signal out_reg_int, out_reg_out_int : SIGNED((data_width*2)-1 DOWNTO 0);

TYPE bus_array3 IS ARRAY (num_reg-1 DOWNTO num_in_reg) OF Signed(data_width-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL out_reg_in: bus_array3; -- for output register inputs
SIGNAL result: bus_array3; -- for results

op_a <= SIGNED(reg_out(0)(data_width-1 DOWNTO 0)); -- operand A
op_b <= SIGNED(reg_out(1)(data_width-1 DOWNTO 0)); -- operand B (trigger register)

-- Multiply Accumulate Operation
out_reg_int <= (op_a * op_b) + out_reg_out_int; -- multiply operands and add to current result

out_reg_out_int <= result(3) & result(2); -- combining the output registers lower and higher parts

out_reg_in(2) <= out_reg_int(data_width-1 downto 0); -- lower part of the result
out_reg_in(3) <= out_reg_int((data_width*2)-1 downto data_width); -- upper part of the result

------------------------------------------------------
-- Basically a register for pre place and route simulation.
------------------------------------------------------
result_regs: FOR J IN num_in_reg TO num_reg-1 GENERATE
Razor_result : entity work.Razor(Behavioral)
Generic Map (data_size => data_width)
Port Map (clk => CLK,
             rst => Test_rst,
             data => std_logic_vector(out_reg_in(J)),
             wen => out_reg_en(J),
             signed(data_out) => result(J),
             error => Razor_error_int(J));   
End Generate;
```

In the Testbench `op_a` is `x64` and `op_b` is `x100` and `out_reg_int`, `out_reg_in` and `out_reg_out_int` are all `0`.

The full code for the unit is This :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use work.DigEng.All;

entity MAC is
Generic (data_size : INTEGER := 71; -- size of data
         num_in_reg: INTEGER := 2; -- number of input registers
         data_width: INTEGER := 64; --size of data minus parity bits
         num_reg   : INTEGER := 4);-- number of input and output registers 
PORT (CLK : IN STD_LOGIC;
      rst       : IN  STD_LOGIC; -- reset
      en_all    : IN  STD_LOGIC; -- enable for all sequential elements
      test_mode : IN  STD_LOGIC; -- Hamming Fault Tolerance Testing
      reg_input : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(data_size-1 downto 0);
      reg_output : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(data_size-1 downto 0);
      error_en  : IN  STD_LOGIC;    -- Hamming Error enable
      we_regs   : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(num_reg-1   DOWNTO 0); -- registers write enable 
      re_regs   : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(num_reg-1   DOWNTO 0); -- registers read enable
      Razor_error : OUT STD_LOGIC; -- Timing error occured
      HW_Error  : OUT STD_LOGIC); -- Error signal for FU replacement 
end MAC;

architecture Behavioral of MAC is

---------------------------
-- Components declaration
---------------------------

    -- Declaring D flipflop
    COMPONENT d_ff IS 
    PORT(clk : IN  STD_LOGIC;
         rst : IN  STD_LOGIC;
         en  : IN  STD_LOGIC;
         data: IN  STD_LOGIC;          
         q   : OUT STD_LOGIC);      
    END COMPONENT;

--------------------
-- Internal signals 
--------------------
    -- Type declaration to array of buses for Outputs of all registers 
    TYPE bus_array IS ARRAY (num_reg-1 DOWNTO 0) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(data_size-1 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL reg_out: bus_array; -- for registers outputs

     TYPE bus_array4 IS ARRAY (num_in_reg-1 DOWNTO 0) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(data_size-1 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL reg_input_int: bus_array4; -- for registers outputs

     TYPE bus_array3 IS ARRAY (num_reg-1 DOWNTO num_in_reg) OF Signed(data_width-1 DOWNTO 0);
     SIGNAL out_reg_in: bus_array3; -- for output register inputs
     SIGNAL result: bus_array3; -- for results

     TYPE bus_array5 IS ARRAY (num_reg-1 DOWNTO num_in_reg) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(data_size-1 DOWNTO 0);
     Signal post_op_hamming_in : bus_array5;

    -- Input registers enables 
    TYPE reg_en IS ARRAY (num_in_reg-1 DOWNTO 0) OF STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL in_reg_en: reg_en;

    -- Output registers enables 
    TYPE reg_en2 IS ARRAY (num_reg-1 DOWNTO num_in_reg) OF STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL out_reg_en: reg_en2;

    -- Oprand A, operand B and operation trigger
    SIGNAL op_a, op_b : SIGNED(data_width-1 DOWNTO 0);
     Signal test_Input1, test_Input2, test_Output_High, test_Output_low : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(data_width-1 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL t_op, test_rst, test_en, test_rst_int, test_en_delayed : STD_LOGIC; -- enable for the output registers
    Signal out_reg_int, out_reg_out_int : SIGNED((data_width*2)-1 DOWNTO 0);

    SIGNAL In_Hamming_out : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(data_size-1 DOWNTO 0);
    Signal Razor_error_int : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(Num_reg-1 downto 0);

BEGIN
-----------------------------------------------
-- Logic for the sequential elements enable
-----------------------------------------------
-- For input registers
input_regs_en: FOR H IN 0 TO num_in_reg-1 GENERATE
    in_reg_en(H) <= (we_regs(H) AND en_all) OR Test_en;
END GENERATE;

-- Instantiate D flipflop
Inst_d_ff: d_ff 
PORT MAP(clk  => clk ,
         rst  => rst,
         en   => en_all,    -- delay the trigger signal for a clock cycle
            data => we_regs(1), -- delayed reg(1) write enable is used as trigger
         q    => t_op);

-- For output registers         
output_regs_en: FOR I IN num_in_reg TO num_reg-1 GENERATE
    out_reg_en(I) <= (t_op AND we_regs(1) AND en_all) OR Test_en ;
END GENERATE;



-------------------------------------------------
-- Instantiate hamming module to check input data
-------------------------------------------------
In_Hamming_module: entity work.Hamming_Module(Behavioral) 
Generic Map (data_size => data_size)
PORT MAP(Data_in   => reg_input,
         Data_out  => In_Hamming_out,
         Error_en  => error_en,
         Error_sig => OPEN);

--------------------------------------------------------
-- Razor Shadow Latch Unit for checking Timing on Input
--------------------------------------------------------
input_regs: FOR J IN 0 TO num_in_reg-1 GENERATE
    Razor_In : entity work.Razor(Behavioral)
    Generic Map (data_size => data_size)
    Port Map (clk  => CLK,
                 rst  => rst,
                 data => reg_input_int(J),
                 wen  => in_reg_en(J),
                 data_out => reg_out(J),
                 error => Razor_error_int(J));
END GENERATE;

------------------------------------------------------
-- Razor Shadow Latch Unit for checking Timing post OP
------------------------------------------------------
result_regs: FOR J IN num_in_reg TO num_reg-1 GENERATE
    Razor_result : entity work.Razor(Behavioral)
    Generic Map (data_size => data_width)
    Port Map (clk => CLK,
                 rst => Test_rst,
                 data => std_logic_vector(out_reg_in(J)),
                 wen => out_reg_en(J),
                 signed(data_out) => result(J),
                 error => Razor_error_int(J));   
End Generate;

------------------------------------------------------
-- Instantiate hamming module to recalculate
-- parity values after operations 
------------------------------------------------------
hamming_post_ops: FOR J IN num_in_reg TO num_reg-1 GENERATE
post_op_hamming_in(J) <= std_logic_vector(resize(result(J), data_size));

hamming_post_ops: entity work.Hamming_Module(Behavioral) 
Generic Map (data_size => data_size)
PORT MAP(Data_in   => post_op_hamming_in(J),
         Data_out  => reg_out(J),
         Error_en  => '0',
         Error_sig => OPEN);
End Generate;

----------------------------
-- MAC Testing
----------------------------
Mac_Tester_Unit : entity work.MAC_Tester(Behavioral)
Generic Map(data_size => data_size,  -- size of data
                num_in_reg => num_in_reg, -- number of input registers
                data_width => data_width, -- size of data minus parity bits
                num_reg => num_reg)    -- number of input and output registers)
Port Map(clk => clk,
            en_all => Test_en,
            Input_reg1 => test_Input1,
            Input_reg2 => test_Input2,
            Output_reg_lower => test_Output_High,
            Output_reg_higher => test_Output_low,
            rst => test_rst_int);

--------------------------------------------------------
-- Assigning the output of input registers to operands 
--------------------------------------------------------
op_a <= SIGNED(reg_out(0)(data_width-1 DOWNTO 0)); -- operand A
op_b <= SIGNED(reg_out(1)(data_width-1 DOWNTO 0)); -- operand B (trigger register)

-- Multiply Accumulate Operation
out_reg_int <= (op_a * op_b) + out_reg_out_int; -- multiply operands and add to current result

out_reg_out_int <= result(3) & result(2); -- combining the output registers lower and higher parts

out_reg_in(2) <= out_reg_int(data_width-1 downto 0); -- lower part of the result
out_reg_in(3) <= out_reg_int((data_width*2)-1 downto data_width); -- upper part of the result

----------------------------------------------------------------
-- Tri-state buffer to output the chosen register output to the
-- central data bus
----------------------------------------------------------------
connections2: FOR J IN num_in_reg TO num_reg-1 GENERATE
    reg_output <= reg_out(J) WHEN re_regs(J) = '1' ELSE (OTHERS => 'Z');
END GENERATE;   

Razor_error <= Razor_error_int(0) OR Razor_error_int(1) OR Razor_error_int(2) OR Razor_error_int(3);

-----------------------------
-- Test Vector Assignment
-----------------------------
Test_en <= '1' When we_regs = "0000" AND re_regs = "0000" AND en_all = '1' AND error_en = '1' else '0';

Test_rst <= Test_rst_int When Test_en = '1' else rst;

reg_input_int(0)(data_width-1 downto 0) <=  test_Input1 when Test_en = '1' else
                            In_Hamming_out(data_width-1 downto 0);
reg_input_int(1)(data_width-1 downto 0) <=  test_Input2 when Test_en = '1' else
                            In_Hamming_out(data_width-1 downto 0);

------------------------------------------------------                          
-- Instantiate D flipflop for delaying output testing
------------------------------------------------------
Test_d_ff: d_ff 
PORT MAP(clk  => clk ,
         rst  => rst,
         en   => en_all,
            data => Test_en, -- delay Test_en for 1 clock cycle for output check
         q    => Test_en_delayed);

HW_Error <= '0' When Test_en_delayed <= '0' OR (signed(test_Output_High) = result(3) AND signed(test_Output_low) = result(2)) else
                '1';

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: If you don't post a [mcve], we cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: I just posted part of it, because the whole unit is rather large due to fault tolerance implementations, but there must be some problem with this part because of the testbenches I ran.

Comment: Any help would be most welcome however and I would happily provide any necessary information, I just didn't want to post a total of probably 1000 lines of code on here. I would be happy about any idea why this behaviour is occurring.

Comment: This example is not minimal, nor complete. Thus we cannot verify it. The only suggestion I can make now is that you should break up your design into smaller parts and increase test coverage.

Comment: But when I isolated it and tested it separately the same process worked. What I find most puzzling is how `out_reg_int <= op_a * op_b`, which I also tried to see if the addition was causing some problem, could possibly not work when `op_a` and `op_b` have the correct values. It seems like it isn't connected, but * is a standard numeric_STD function, so that should definitely work. And I am not sure how it can be both minimal and complete. minimal would mean only the lines in question, whereas complete would mean all code in the unit.

Comment: could it be that your simulator has problems displaying 72-bit and/or 144-bit values?